# Hiding the entire column from a table in a rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Actually I would like to hide all the columns from a table in rails view, if those columns contains no data i.e., zero.

Secondly, I want to delete the respective row completely if quantity == 0.

Find the screenshot for better understanding as below;

[screenshot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zbx8.png)

index.html.erb

```
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

        <div class="table-responsive myTable">

            <table class="table listing text-center">
                <tr class="tr-head">
                    <td>DESCRIPTION</td>
                    <td>COLOR</td>
                    <td>QUANTITY</td>
                    <td>RETAIL PRICE</td>
                    <td>TOTAL AMOUNT</td>
                    <td>CARTON NO</td>
                    <td>CUSTOMER 1</td>
                    <td>CUSTOMER 2</td>
                    <td>ACTUAL QUANTITY</td>
                </tr>

                <% @purchases.each do |purchase| %>

                <tr class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

                    <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.description %></td>
                    <td class="col-1"><%= purchase.color %></td>
                    <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.quantity %></td>
                    <td class="col-2"><%= number_with_precision(purchase.rprice, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>        
                    <td class="col-2"><%= number_with_precision(purchase.tamount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>  
                    <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.cartonno %></td>
                    <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.cus1 %></td>
                    <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.cus2 %></td>
                    <td class="col-2"><%= tquantity = purchase.quantity - purchase.cus1 - purchase.cus2 %></td>

                </tr>

                <% end %>

            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

purchases_controller.rb

```
class PurchasesController < ApplicationController
        before_action :set_purchase, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /Stockings
  # GET /deldetails.json
  def index
    #@purchases = Purchase.all
    @purchases = Purchase.where("tquantity !=?", 0)
  end

  def import
    Purchase.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to purchases_url, notice: "Purchases imported."
  end

  # GET /purchases/1
  # GET /purchases/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /purchases/new
  def new
    @purchase = Purchase.new
  end

  # GET /purchases/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /purchases
  # POST /purchases.json
  def create
    @purchase = Purchase.new(purchase_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @purchase.save
        format.html { redirect_to @purchase, notice: 'Purchase was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @purchase }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @purchase.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /purchases/1
  # PATCH/PUT /purchases/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @purchase.update(purchase_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @purchase, notice: 'Purchase was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @purchase }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @purchase.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /purchases/1
  # DELETE /purchases/1.json
  def destroy
    @purchase.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to purchases_url, notice: 'Purchase was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_purchase
      @purchase = Purchase.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def purchase_params
      params.require(:purchase).permit(:season, :category, :articleno, :description, :color, :quantity, :rprice, :tamount, :cartonno, :cus1, :cus2, :tquantity )
    end
end
```

purchase.rb

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.import(file)
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
            Purchase.create! row.to_hash
        end
    end

end
```

Do I need to go for if else or ternary operator for checking the for the columns if it is empty or not ?

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a condition in your view.

```
 <% unless @purchases.collect{|p| p.cus2}.uniq == [0] %>
   <td>CUSTOMER 2</td>
 <% end %>
```

and

```
    <% @purchases.each do |purchase| %>
      <% unless purchase.quantity == 0 %>
            <tr class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

                <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.description %></td>
                <td class="col-1"><%= purchase.color %></td>
                <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.quantity %></td>
                <td class="col-2"><%= number_with_precision(purchase.rprice, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>        
                <td class="col-2"><%= number_with_precision(purchase.tamount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>  
                <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.cartonno %></td>
                <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.cus1 %></td>
                <% unless @purchases.collect{|p| p.cus2}.uniq == [0] %>
                  <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.cus2 %></td>
                <% end %>
                <td class="col-2"><%= tquantity = purchase.quantity - purchase.cus1 - purchase.cus2 %></td>

            </tr>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

and to remove row with 0 quantity the best thing is do not select those records having 0 quantity with in query.

```
@purchases = Purchase.where("quantity !=?", 0)
```

or alternatively I also have updated the view code which is less recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.With this logic @purchases = Purchase.where("cus2 !=?", 0) , i am losing all the data of the respective rows except where cus2 != 0. I want to hide the cus2 column completely when all its values are 0. Hope you understand the matter.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much.Secondly, I want to delete the respective row completely if actual quantity == 0.

Comment: I have update my answer again please check for <% unless purchase.quantity == 0 %> condition

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried with the <% unless purchase.tquantity == 0 %> condition as well since my actual quantity field is tquantity in database. For  better understanding I have added new screenshot.

Comment: I also tried with this, @purchases = Purchase.where("tquantity !=?", 0) and it removes all the records.

Comment: what is the datatype of the tquanity? can you share result of Purchase.first.tquantity,class from rails console.

Comment: irb(main):058:0> Purchase.first.tquantity
  Purchase Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "purchases".* FROM "purchases"  ORDER BY "purchases"."id" ASC LIMIT
 1
=> nil

Comment: Purchase.first.tquantity.class should be Fixnum

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That means it is not referencing to anything that is why it is NilClass, if so then how should I proceed to make it as Fixnum.

Comment: 2.2.0 :006 > Purchase.first.tquantity.class
  Purchase Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "purchases".* FROM "purchases"  ORDER BY "purchases"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => Fixnum 
But still not working...

Comment: can you please provide your model and controller code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the model and controller code for your reference. Secondly, is this code correct in my index.html.erb just review,<td class="col-2"><%= tquantity = purchase.quantity - purchase.cus1 - purchase.cus2 %></td> , for all other fields we call purchase.something but for this we are calling directly tquantity. And when I import the file everytime I am getting nil as it is not taking the values.

Answer (score 0):

I have understand your problem. But why are you taking those records inside the instance varible `@purchases`.

You should write a query or scope like so that will exclude the record which have the values zero inside the column.

Lets have a example like as below...

```
Class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :exclude_zero_value_customers, -> { where('cus1 <> ? && cus2 <> ?', 0,0) }
end
```

Or you can hide it directly from the view as well, But in that case if you have thousands of records then also it will go one time with that loop as bwlow...

```
<% @purchases.each do |purchase| %>
       <% if !purchase.cus1.zero? && !purchase.cus2.zero? %>

            <tr class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

                <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.description %></td>
                <td class="col-1"><%= purchase.color %></td>
                <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.quantity %></td>
                <td class="col-2"><%= number_with_precision(purchase.rprice, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>        
                <td class="col-2"><%= number_with_precision(purchase.tamount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>  
                <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.cartonno %></td>
                <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.cus1 %></td>
                <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.cus2 %></td>
                <td class="col-2"><%= tquantity = purchase.quantity - purchase.cus1 - purchase.cus2 %></td>

            </tr>

       <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. None of the logic are working for me.